# How to create a simple shopping cart without Drupal Commerce or Ubercart?

Tags: views, commerce, 7

I want to make a simple order web site for selling some poster. I don't need to add to basket or complicated order stuff. I need only list my posters in catalog view and when clicked one of them appear detail about poster. And in the detailed page I need an order button and then order form.

What is the best way for this? I mean I use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) for catalog and detail page. My question is How to configure when user click an catalog item and the user goes to detailed page with created views?

Comment: Your question is still vague. How do you intend to collect payment? Use a credit card processor? Mail-In check? What?  1 easy way to integrate a Payment method is to use something like a Paypal buy-now button, or for instance mals-e.com buy now buttons linked to from your View. Such services are sometimes free for small volumes of transactions -- or a paid monthly service.

You're asking for alot of work by trying to re-implement ordering forms without using a Drupal shopping cart module on your own site.

Comment: I will not use auto payment. first i see orders and asking payment after.

Comment: Best to just use D7 Commerce. It'll do all that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should just use webform or entityform. With the flag module you can achieve that multiple items can be ordered. If there is no need for payment or checkout like in a 'normal' webshop, do not make it more complicatet than it is: actually you want your visitors to be in contact about one or more items on you website and get their details.

Answer (score 1):

Below are 2 possible alternatives (options) for setting up a simple shopping cart without using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) or [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) modules (as in your question title).

## Option 1: A lightweight e-shop

**If** you're only looking for a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution, **Then** have a looking at the [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module (for D7, not for D6, not (yet?) for D8). Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

## Option 2: A simple shopping cart

**If** you're only looking for a shopping cart (as in your title), **Then** have a looking at the [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module (for D7, not for D6, not (yet?) for D8). Here is a quote from its project page:

> Basic cart is a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few products or other content types being sold, for example touristic offers.
>
> **Main difference from Ubercart and Commerce:**
>
> The main difference from Ubercart and Commerce is the possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart. It also doesn't bother you with the Product SKU, that can be a pain when you have just a few products.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - The possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart.
> - The possibility of sending, or not, an email to the customer once an order is placed.
> - Custom email messages for both the site administrator and the customer, along with the order details.
> - Order registration and listing in the administration area using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
> - Integration with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
> - A block with the contents of your shopping cart.

Here is a screenshot of it (note the "**Checkout**" button also ...):

[image]