# What to choose Content Type or Drupal Commerce or Ubercart

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, ubercart

I'm working on a project where we've people managing product in site (including product creation, editing, viewing, reviewing, etc.). These are not going to be techie people so the product management should be easy to use with quick loading. The site as of now doesn't allow users to sell and buy product online (It might allow in future, but not confirmed - very less chances). Its just viewing, reviewing, rating products. Also there will be variety of product. We're also planning on creating Mobile App for this so user can manage products from App.

As I've already worked with all of these 3 earlier, my personal thought is that [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) may add an extra overhead of e-commerce functionality on our site. I need suggestion on how should we proceed here, what things should we consider while selecting any one of these 3. What should be best choice to go ahead in such scenario i.e. Plain content type or Drupal Commerce or Ubercart.

Comment: If you are not going to sell products then just use content types and adding ratings. Easy to use for end user and you don't need to configure Drupal Commerce or Ubercart stuff if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks @pgrujic, for quick reply. Yes, but how best we can manage variety of product types using content type considering easy to use ui and performance?

Comment: There are too many possible answers to that question @Yogesh. You need to put a proof of concept together and see which scenario supports your specific needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go (start with) what you call "Plain content types".

For the "rating" requirements, have a look at my answer to "[What are recommended modules or processes which support rating based comments or reviews?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163014/what-are-recommended-modules-or-processes-which-support-rating-based-comments-or/163021#163021)".

Should you ever want to expand that to a (rather basic) e-shop and/or add a shopping cart, you can always use the modules as I suggested in my answer to "[How to create a simple shopping cart without Drupal Commerce or Ubercart?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82103/how-to-create-a-simple-shopping-cart-without-drupal-commerce-or-ubercart/185051#185051)".

Next question?

Answer (score 1):

> We're also planning on creating Mobile App for this so user can manage
>   products from App.

I highly suggest you go with Drupal 8 as it's mobile ready and friendly.

If you are not selling anything, content types is the way to go.

For displaying various products you can use the Views module, which comes with Drupal 8.

For performance Drupal 8 automatically caches your pages and clears the cache when you make changes.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but we've reviewed that already and there are many other modules which are not available for D8, few of them are Location, FiveStar, Voting API, etc. so D8 won't be good option in our case.